# cron running init.d reload and getting exit code of 2

Tags: 14.04, bash, permissions, cron, init.d

I am having cron run a shell script which includes this line...

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

but it is giving me an exit code of 2...What can I do to reload nginx from cron successfully?

Comment: Does `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` run successfully from command line?

Comment: yes it most certainly does

Comment: Then it should work on `cron` too..what `cron` entry you have exactly?

Comment: like I said, my cronjob is calling a .sh script which is logging things to files, I was getting some strange behavior on some if statements so I logged the exit code and this one was 2. It may be restarting nginx but just returning a different code, IDK